# Adding ADODB RecordSet item to Collection

Tags: vba, reference, oledb, adodb, recordset

I'm new to VBA, trying to write an Outlook macro around an Excel spreadsheet via Microsoft's ACE OLEDB Provider. I'm looping through the `ResultSet` after a query and storing the results in a `Collection`, along the lines of the following:

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

Sub Test()
   Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
   Dim results As New ADODB.Recordset
   Dim values As Object
   Set values = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

   conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\Users\me\test.xlsx;" & _
     "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;"""

   results.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", _
     conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
   Do Until results.EOF
     values.Add results.Fields.Item("num")
     Debug.Print Join(values.toArray, ", ")
     results.MoveNext
   Loop
End Sub
```

With the following `test.xlsx`:

[image: Test Excel data]

We get:

```
1
2, 2
3, 3, 3
4, 4, 4, 4
5, 5, 5, 5, 5
```

This seems consistent with `results.Fields.Item("column_name")` returning a reference that is overwritten at each `MoveNext`, and the reference being what's stored in `values`.

Not being very familiar with the reference/value mechanics in VBA, is this guess on the right track, and is there some way I can store the values instead?

Answer (score 0):

Does this code even compile?

I've never heard of an `ADODB.Resultset` unless this is .NET???
What library do you have to reference to find this object?

Are you trying to reference a Recordset?

You're using `Dim result As New ADODB.ResultSet`
Then

`result.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"`

but your loop is using the plural '**results'**

Comment: IIRC I'm referencing `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects [6.1]` re: [this Office Space](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx). The example isn't 100% faithful to the live code, but I was hoping the issue was common enough to recognize the form. Thanks for pointing out the `result` slipup!

Comment: I think you need to copy the code and then edit it for your use. There's no ResultSet in that article - it's called Recordset there too. As a point of future reference we're not here to troubleshoot code that hasn't even been tested yourself. Once you get it going it might work better to put the debug join statement outside the loop - but that's is just a big guess right now

Comment: Fair enough, I admittedly asked initially in haste. On my work machine, I've now been able to reproduce the behavior with the updated example.

Comment: As I suggested earlier - Put your debug statement outside the loop

Comment: In this case I can't -- probably because the array is referencing a results.Fields.Item, it errors with "Either BOF or EOF is true..."

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but it's the top result on Google, so an answer is probably in order.

When you add items to a collection from a recordset using results.Fields.Item("column_name") or results!column_name, it's added as a reference, so when the collection looks up the value, it gets the same result over and over (also, if you close the recordset, you will get an EOF error at each index).

Instead, what you need to do is add the field Value

MyCollection_.Add results.Fields("column_name").value